# Как из ubuntu открыть ссылку, если сервер на хостинге, который ее обслуживает блочит подобные запросы?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nginx, url, хостинг

Есть необходимость открыть ссылку, но при попытке сделать это курлом в Ubuntu выдается следующая информация:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При этом вручную через браузер url спокойно открывается. Подскажите, как можно это сделать? Неужели никак?

Comment: `sudo curl` - никогда так не делайте

Comment: Нужно добыть из браузера куки. Можно их добыть через расширение, можно через пункт меню `Copy as cURL` в Chrome Dev Tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для начала открой инспектор хром и открой потом эту ссылку. На вкладке network инспектора скопируй длинную команду правой кнопкой - copy as curl

Comment: у меня там выбор copy as a curl for bash и copy as curl for cmd, выбрал bash, вот что выдает: curl 'http://f90577wq.beget.tech/run' \
  -H 'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7' \
 и еще много всего, что в форму комментария не поместилось очень. большой текст

Comment: ну вот и попробуй этой длинной командой. запускаешь в баше - значит для баша